# Git – adding and commiting large files locally gives "BAD" file in the repo

Tags: git

I have a data directory with a lot of small files and some files that are around 5 GB. I don't intend to upload the project to a cloud service, I just want local version control. The large files are not added correctly to the git repository in the `.git`-directory. This is not about GitHub, BitBucket or similar.

I ran `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -m "First"` to test. But the result from `git ls-tree -r -l` was that the size of the large files is 1.5 GB (but should be ~5 GB). Clearly, something was wrong, so I deleted the .git directory and created the repo once more, and this time the size of the large files was reported to be `BAD`.

What is wrong? Can't Git handle files of 5 GB size? I'm aware of Git LFS. But as I understand it, that is for remotely storing large files, i.e. in the cloud. That's not what I want. I just want simple, local version control, so I can easily roll back my model (I do CFD modelling) if I mess something up. A large .git-directory is not a problem for me. Do I really have to use LFS for that purpose?

EDIT: I tried the command `git ls-tree -r -l master` in WSL instead of Windows Powershell. Now the file size shows the right value, i.e. 5669792043, and not "BAD". Why did this work in Linux in Windows, and not in native Windows?

EDIT 2: I've learned that there is a bug in Git for Windows that prevent you from adding files larger than 4 GB. The bug is discussed [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1063).

[Here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2434#issuecomment-1007419305) they claim that the bug was fixed in Git for Windows 2.34. But I'm still confused. The output from my `git --version --build-options` shows `git version 2.43.0.windows.1`, but I still get this error. For my part, I'll just use WSL to circumvent the problem altogether in the future.

Comment: Not sure you'll need that, but note that the size threshold for files to be considered "big" is settable in config ([`core.bigFileThreshold`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corebigFileThreshold)).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. In this case it's absolutely OK to label the files "big", as they are both big and binary. I have another repository for another simulation with some geotiff files that are > 3GB. There is no problem with them. So for me, at this point, it seems like an error in Git. But how to fix it or prevent it?